# Offering multiple versions of artifact heavy package

Tags: packages

I am developing a package that requires some very large (>50 Mb in some cases) artifacts to work for some of its features. This makes distributing this package annoying, as if I include these artifacts inside my bundled package, users will have to install a huge dependency even if they might not even need said artifact. On the flip side, if I don't include these artifacts, this might be annoying/confusing for some users as they will need to manage these themselves. For this reason I'm considering publishing three versions of my package:

- The package like described, including all artifacts and being very large in size
- A lightweight version of the package, only including the code but not the huge artifacts. Note that this means it's up to the user to pass in the required artifacts for the functions that require them.
- A wrapper package to be optionally used with the lightweight version of my package that contains just the artifacts and some functions to access them.

This is what I came up with off the top of my head, however this doesn't seem very user friendly and I'd like to know how I can do better. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see two votes to close this question, but I'm not sure why. It concerns dependency management and how to solve the problem of a large package where not every component is always necessary. This should be perfectly on-topic for this community.  A good question, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen a number of packages that come in two versions at least - one full, suitable for offline installation, and a lightweight version which loads missing parts from the internet lazily. If your download page explains in what circumstances the lightweight version is suitable (user either does not need the feature, or does not know yet but has a suitable internet connection when running the software) the user can make an informed decision and still has comfortable installation packages.

Requiring the user to provide the missing files manually as in your second option is probably too burdensome. An automatic download is pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Download the heavy artifact lazily, on first feature access. Arguably proper progress reporting explaining the wait to end user is the most complex part of the implementation.

This is especially suitable for a product that already requires Internet connectivity.

Comment: I perfectly agree to this approach in general, but I think one should think this a little bit further.  *"This is especially suitable for a product that already requires Internet connectivity."* sounds like an  euphemism for *"this is unsuitable for a product which might be forbidden to access the internet"* - so it would be better to invest some thoughts into the latter case. And the most complex part of the implementation is probably to make this secure.

Comment: @DocBrown a necessity of full package for offline use was implied (I wanted to limit the answer to exactly one option). Secure download is a non-issue given your artifact hosting has a proper SSL certificate.